# Раскрыть, свернуть блок при нажатии на однукнопку

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть кнопка

```
 <a class="review-open">Оставить отзыв</a>
```

При нажатии на нее раскрывается блок

```
$( ".review-open" ).click(function() {

          $( ".review" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
        });
```

Как сделать так что бы при нажатии на нее же, он закрывался?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
let reviewOpen = false; // Переменная, которая отвечает за статус открытия/закрытия блока с отзывом
$(".review-open").click(function() {
  if (!reviewOpen) { //если блок закрыт
    $(".review").slideDown("slow", function() { //открываем его
      // Animation complete.
      reviewOpen = true; //и меняем статус на открытый
    });
  } else { //а если блок открыт
    $(".review").slideUp("slow", function() { //закрываем его
      // Animation complete.
      reviewOpen = false; //и, соответственно, меняем статус на закрытый
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.review {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="review-open">Оставить отзыв</a>
<div class="review">Пытаемся оставить отзыв здесь</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В JQuery есть метод [slideToggle](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_effect_slidetoggle.php), который позволяет сделать то, что Вам нужно

```
$(".review-open" ).click(function() {
    $( ".review" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
});
```